# Line Integration Solution Check

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

If curve $C$ is the curve on both cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and plane $z=ax+by-1$ with $a,b\neq0$, calculate $\int_Cf\,ds$ for $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z$.

I used this parametrization:

- $x=\cos t$
- $y=\sin t$
- $z=a \cos t+ b\sin t-1$

So it becomes:

$\vec{r}=(\cos t,\,\sin t,\,a\cos t+b\sin t-1)$

$d\vec{r}=(-\sin t,\,\cos t,\,-a\sin t+b\cos t)\,dt$

$ds=\sqrt{\sin^2t+\cos^2t+(b\cos t-a\sin t)^2}\,dt=\sqrt{1+(b\cos t-a\sin t)^2}\,dt$

So the integral becomes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}(a\cos t+b\sin t)\sqrt{1+(b\cos t-a\sin t)^2}\,dt$$
With variable change $u=b\cos t-a\sin t$, it becomes:
$$-\int\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du$$
$$=-\dfrac{(1+u^2)u+\ln(u+(1+u^2))}{2}$$

But actually, for $t=0$, $u=b$ and for $t=2\pi$, $u=b$. Hence the integral must be zero. Am I right? If it's true that answer is zero, is there a better way (e.g. by symmetry) that we can understand that the answer is zero from the beginning?

Comment: No need to parameterize. You're on the cylinder, so $f(x,y,z)=1+z=ax+by$. The curve itself is a rotated ellipse in 3D space. Can you see why exactly half of the curve lies to either side of the plane $z=0$?

Comment: You mean it's zero by symmetry? I don't get it actually. I've read a lot about it but I need an explanation if possible please. @user170231

Comment: Yes, symmetry is the key. I'm saying that you want to compute $\displaystyle\int_C(ax+by)\,ds$, whose integrand is easy to visualize, just pick virtually any plane containing the origin. Now notice the plane $z=0$ cuts this plane in half. What does it do to $C$?